# What version of .NET ships with what version of Windows?

Tags: .net, windows, version, .net-framework-version

Looking for a list of Windows versions (service packs included) and what version of .NET is natively<sup>1</sup> available.

Example:

Windows A - .NET Framework Z
Windows A Service Pack 1 - .NET Framework Z
Windows A Service Pack 2 - .NET Framework Y

---

<sup>1</sup> By natively I mean that is there with no installs done.

Comment: [Windows is not a .NET Framework delivery channel](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110404-00/?p=11043/)

Comment: Perhaps Wikipedia's [.Net Framework History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#History) would be helpful.

Comment: Any updates for Windows 10?

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 see the link in the accepted answer - it shows 4.6 is included

Comment: This is the most useful summary I have found: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This should give you all the answers you want:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#Overview

Due to the fact that new versions of .NET are being released all the time I felt it would not be correct to try to embed the history into this answer, but merely direct you to a source which is updated.

Comment: I'll save you a click: Anything before Windows 2003: nuffin; Windows 2003: 1.1; Vista & 2008: 3.0; Windows 7 & 2008 R2: 3.5

Comment: Actually: Win7 will include 3.5 SP1

Comment: Windows 8 is 4.5, Windows 8.1 is 4.5.1 and Windows 10 is 4.6

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os.aspx

Answer (score 23):

The following picture explains it perfectly:

[image: which-version-of-net-is-built-into]

source: http://petermarcu.blogspot.ie/2010/02/which-version-of-net-is-built-into.html

Answer (score 22):

Microsoft released a chart for this.
[.NET Framework Versions and Dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies)

A checkmark means its included, a plus sign means it can be installed.