# What is the .NET version installed by default?

Tags: .net, windows-xp, version, default, portability

I want to create a very portable app and ideally everybody should be able to use it without the need to install .NET. What is the default .NET version used at most not-programmers machines? Is it .NET2 or .NET1 on Windows XP with SP2 or SP3?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What version of .NET ships with what version of Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909516/what-version-of-net-ships-with-what-version-of-windows)

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk it might be a duplicate, but only here there is a right answer.

Comment: not quite. The info in the correct answer here is the same as in [the linked wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Versions) in that other answer (apart from that fact that wikipedia does not list XP, but on the other hand lists the Windows Server versions). That link also has the advantage of pointing to a page that is likely to be updated on future releases, which might not be the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- .NET 2.0 comes with Windows XP SP2
- .NET 3.5 comes with Windows 7

Why don't you bundle the .Net Framework Installer together with your application?

If the user is up-to-date with the Windows Update, it should have the .Net 3.5.

Comment: but the user could not have administrator and have restricted account, so I would rather just target the 2.0.

Comment: Can you cite a source regarding XP SP2. TIA.

Answer (score 3):

It is depending on the Operating System, and the service packs, if any.

If you're targeting multiple Windows versions, it's inevitable to include .NET in your installation.

Answer (score 2):

Windows XP comes without .Net installed.

```
Version  Version Number Release Date    Default in Windows
1.0      1.0.3705.0      2002-02-13     
1.1      1.1.4322.573    2003-04-24 Windows Server 2003
2.0      2.0.50727.42    2005-11-07 Windows Server 2003 R2
3.0      3.0.4506.30     2006-11-06 Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008
3.5      3.5.21022.8     2007-11-19 Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2
4.0      4.0.30319.1     2010-04-12
```