# Which .Net version does windows 10 have built-in?

Tags: .net, windows, windows-10

I want to know which .Net version does windows 10 have built-in?
like Windows 7 comes with 3.0 and 3.5 .Net pre-installed by default.

Comment: It has the version you need.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there have already been multiple "Editions" of Windows 10 and each one comes with different .NET versions built-in. As such, any answer here is likely to be outdated unless it turns into a list answer, which we don't really need.

Comment: To expand the comment from @Damien_The_Unbeliever "Windows 10" can refer to a series of different versions, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10/release-information and each of them ship with different .NET Framework versions (4.6.x/4.7.x and upcoming 4.8.x), so it is too broad to provide an answer, and the readers should check the concrete versions in use.

Comment: See [What version of .NET ships with what version of Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/909516/5170571)

Answer (score 60):

Here is a [link to Microsoft Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/astebner/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os) that answers "**What version of the .NET Framework is included in what version of the OS?**"

> Windows 10 (all editions) includes the .NET Framework 4.6 as an OS component, and it is installed by default.  It also includes the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 as an OS component that is not installed by default.  The .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 can be added or removed via the Programs and Features control panel.

Details from the link:

- Windows 10 1507 (all editions) includes the .NET Framework 4.6.0
- Windows 10 1511 November 2015 Update (all editions) includes the .NET Framework 4.6.1
- Windows 10 1607 Anniversary Update (all editions) includes the .NET Framework 4.6.2
- Windows 10 1703 Creators Update (all editions)  includes the .NET Framework 4.7
- Windows 10 1709 Fall 2017 Creators Update (all editions)  includes the .NET Framework 4.7.1
- Windows 10 1803 April 2018 Update (all editions)  includes the .NET Framework 4.7.2
- Windows 10 1903 May 2019 Update (all editions)  includes the .NET Framework 4.8

Comment: I think this documentation here is better, but only lists .NET Framework, not .NET Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies

Comment: @Joel, the link you provided [.NET Framework versions and dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies) is much better, indeed. There is a good summary on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#Overview). Also there is no .Net Core mentioned because it is not a Windows component: [more details](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/4600#issuecomment-725613982).

Answer (score 3):

.NET 4.6 should normally be installed with Windows 10, but it might not be activated. You can also activate 3.5 if you need to. From version 4 onwards, .NET delivers in-place updates, i.e. it is no longer possible to have parallel versions of 4.x installed. Support ends soon for these intermediate versions.

Newer versions might come per Windows update (currently 4.6.1).